# rails delayed_job memory consumption problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

We're having huge problems with the delayed_job plugin - http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/

When we start tasks with "ruby script/delayed_job start", the process never lets go of RAM it acquires.

So it starts with 10%, 25%, gets to 80% and never lets go of the ram, even if it has no jobs to process.

Any ideas how we can get over this?

Thanks!

(PS: RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start didn't work for us to start the delayed_job worker)

Comment: Why doesn't `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start` work for you? Otherwise you're running it in development. In which case, over what time period does this problem occur?

Comment: I've found that shaking the `GC.start` magic stick sometimes prods the garbage collector into actually getting to work.

Comment: You probably have a memory leak somewhere in your application. There are a couple of hints about debugging that issue in the rails guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-memory-leaks)

Comment: @Jason - This happens even when the delayed job queue is completely empty. @tadman - what do you mean by GC.start? I'm new to all of this :(  @wuputah - this is what I get http://pastebin.com/xfPWRKAX - however when I test it it's working fine after I start it with the other command (it runs in production)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on advice from IRC (from @ReinH), Ruby will never free memory back to the OS.

So the only solution I know of right now is to manually restart the delayed_job plugin every now and then.

@ReinH also pointed out the delayed_job_spawner plugin, which seems to be another plausible solution - http://github.com/woahdae/delayed_job_spawner

Comment: wow, i never knew this, but running into it now.  seems like a problem that they need to fix.  Here is a link to this issue: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/336

Comment: FYI: Delayed job with rails 3 seems to be working fine for us - either it doesn't have this problem, or we've done something differently in our setup.